# Call Java -> C -> dll

Tags: java, c, dll, java-native-interface

I'm doing an implementation in Java that I need to send a C function, but it calls a dll too.
This is the C code:

```
int SampleCalibration7points(void){
    
    int sel_coeff_7P, neg_flags;
    
    int i, ret;
    
    int cali_type, cali_points;
    
    // COEFFICIENT_COUNT = 10 
    // global variable
    int coefficients[COEFFICIENT_COUNT] = {0};

    // 7 points calibration
    // complete calibration input, 24 bit values
    // {Pressure_ref[%], Pressure_raw, Tambient_ref, Tambient_raw}
    double cali_data[7][4]  =   {   {30,    982368,     10, 420864},
                                    {90,    7950208,    10, 420901},
                                    {30,    770304,     25, 1571148},
                                    {50,    2362176,    25, 1581184},
                                    {90,    7768800,    25, 1581104},
                                    {30,    547968,     40, 2749136},
                                    {90,    7620416,    40, 2749312}};

    int range_check;
    int test;

    double P_raw[7], P_des[7], T_raw[7],T_raw_back[7], T_des[7];
    double P_corr[7], T_corr[7],P_corr_percent[7], T_corr_deg[7]; 
    
    
    // limit definition
    // pressure limits are 0 and 100, due to percentage reference
    double T_min = -40.0, T_max = 85.0;
     
    // choose coefficient to be calculated

    /*
        //FLAGS for selCoeffs
        #define CO_OFFSET_S         0x1
        #define CO_GAIN_S           0x2
        #define CO_TCG              0x4
        #define CO_TCO              0x8
        #define CO_SOT_TCO          0x10
        #define CO_SOT_TCG          0x20
        #define CO_SOT_S            0x40
        #define CO_OFFSET_T         0x80
        #define CO_GAIN_T           0x100
        #define CO_SOT_T            0x200
    */
    sel_coeff_7P = (CO_OFFSET_S|CO_GAIN_S|CO_TCO|CO_TCG|CO_OFFSET_T|CO_GAIN_T|CO_SOT_TCO|CO_SOT_TCG|CO_SOT_T|CO_SOT_S);    

    // calibration type, default value 
    cali_type = 0;
    
    // number of calibration points
    cali_points = 7;   
    
    // rearrange data for coefficent calculation
    for ( i=0; i < cali_points; i++ ) {
        
        P_raw[i] = cali_data[i][1];
        // generate digital reference pressure values -> P_des[x]
        P_des[i] = ConvertBridgeFromPercent( cali_data[i][0]);
        
        T_raw[i] = cali_data[i][3] ;  
        // generate digital reference temp values -> T_des[x]
        ConvertTempFromDegrees(&T_des[i], cali_data[i][2], T_min, T_max );
    }

    // call DLL function
    // coefficent calculation
    ret = CalculateCoefficients( coefficients,
                                    &neg_flags, 
                                    cali_points, //number of coeffs max 7 
                                    sel_coeff_7P,
                                    cali_type, 
                                    P_raw, P_des, 
                                    T_raw, T_des);    

        /********** Coefficients resulst, T[-40..85]    *************
        coefficients =  {   -520831,
                            5880723,
                            489,
                            379060,
                            -4349,
                                -296970,
                            -278951,
                            -317710,
                            3817446,
                            -49055
                        }
        ***************************************************/
    
    for (i = 0;i<cali_points;i++){
        // call DLL functions
        T_corr[i] = GetCorrectedTemp(coefficients, T_raw[i]);
        ConvertTempToDegrees (&T_corr_deg[i] , (int) T_corr[i],  T_min, T_max );

        P_corr[i] = GetCorrectedBridge (coefficients, P_raw[i] , T_raw[i]); 
        P_corr_percent[i] = ConvertBridgeToPercent(P_corr[i]); 
        // Convert pressure precentage values to the according pressure values, depending on customers limits
    }
        /********** Corrected raw values, applying coefficients *************  
        
        corrected temperature[counts] =         
                            {       
                                 6710884,   
                                 6710949,   
                                 8712632,   
                                 8729989,   
                                 8729851,   
                                10737550,   
                                10737550    
                            }
                            
        corrected pressure [counts]=            
                            {
                                  5033172,  
                                 15099510,  
                                  5033171,  
                                  8388615,  
                                 15099510,  
                                  5033171,  
                                 15099510   
                            }                   
        *******************************************************************/    


    //check coefficients range, returns 1 when range is exceeded, else 0 
    // call DLL function
    range_check = VerifyCoefficients(coefficients) ;                                   
    return 0;
}
```

and the dll is CalibrationL6.dll

For example: CalculateCoefficients is one of the functions that belongs to dll.

Do you know what is the best way to do that? because I don't know if with the JNI functionality my C file keeps calling the dll that is needed.

I tried to call dll (CalibrationL6.dll) directly with Java, but it's not supported, that's why I'm trying to use C code instead.

Comment: We could use a description of "not supported."  Exactly what error do you get?  Did you call (I think it's) `System.loadLibrary()` first?  Where's the JNI code in Java?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you need to actually pass data to this library somewhere? Do you have header files that go with this library? SWIG can help you generate the necessary glue code, or you could give JNA a try to call the functions directly.

Answer (score 0):

please provide the whole because the problem you are stating is in the printf statement, which is not present in the given code. On the top of it i dont know how are you able to get the output as i am getting errors of several undeclared variables.
if you want to calibrate in java then you have to use %d.f rather than dll and use printf statement while typing %d.f rather than println

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).